# Continuous Integration, Continuous Delivery, Continuous Deployment from their application perspectives

Tags: continuous-integration, tfs-2015, continuous-deployment, devops, continuous-delivery

I am using Visual Studio, TFS 2015, Visual Studio Team Services, and Azure/ Local or Remote IIS for achieving Continuous Integration.
I am reading from below stackoverflow [Continuous Integration vs. Continuous Delivery vs. Continuous Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608015/continuous-integration-vs-continuous-delivery-vs-continuous-deployment)

1. Me / my team check in the code to TFS repository and configured automated build each time I check in the code; is it Continuous Integration?
2. I have configured the build. It runs nuget package manager, runs Tests, performs Build and drops the built assembly to specified location. Is it Continuous Delivery?
3. I have configured Deployment to Azure/IIS. Also I have enabled Continuous Integration. So whenever now me/my team checks in the code, it runs build and deploys to the production/stating server. Is it Continuous Deployment?
4. When I perform all of the above in one single click, is it called DevOps?
5. Where the role of Manual Testing using Selenium/MS Build comes into the picture here?

Please add inputs, let me know if I am going wrong anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes. Accurately speaking, it is only a form of CI. In TFS, this is
   called CI build. You can achieved this by select *CI* trigger of the
   build definition.
2. Yes. It's also a way of implementation with Continuous Delivery.
3. Yes.Continuous Deployment is described as the logical next step
   after continuous delivery: Automatically deploy the product into
   production whenever it passes QA.
4. No.**Continuous delivery** and **DevOps** are **similar** in their meanings and are
   often conflated, **but they are two different concepts.** DevOps has a
   broader scope, and centers around the cultural change, specifically
   the collaboration of the various teams involved in software delivery
   (developers, operations, quality assurance, management, etc.), as
   well as automating the processes in software delivery. Continuous
   Delivery, on the other hand, is an approach to automate the delivery
   aspect, and focuses on bringing together different processes and
   executing them more quickly and more frequently. They have common
   end goals and are often used in conjunction to achieve them. DevOps
   and Continuous Delivery share a background in agile methods and lean
   thinking: small and quick changes with focused value to the end
   customer. They are well communicated and collaborated internally,
   thus helping achieve quick time to market, with reduced risk.
5. Manual testing is a **time-consuming** and **labor-intensive** process to
   ensure a piece of software does what it’s supposed to, no matter how
   fast it was developed. Teams sometimes **depend too much on the unit testing** and ignore automation and acceptance testing. CI also has the some risks and challenges. This is just one of them.